# Trigger Issue on Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

My trigger works on Opportunity Stage.Logic is whenever I change Stage I would create record in related object named StageHelper.As I need to capture current and prior age of stage .There is some bug in my code.

I wan't to track stage change history.Whenever I change stage record should create and whenever I go back to same stage it should not create create record instead it should update previous stagehelper record with that stage.

Not understanding what is bug .

```
trigger StageHelper on Opportunity (after update) {
  List<Opportunity> OppList=new List<Opportunity>();
  for(Opportunity Opp:Trigger.new){
  if(Opp.StageName!=Trigger.oldmap.get(Opp.id).stagename){
  OppList.add(opp);
    }    
  } 
 List<StageHelper__c> helperList=[select id,Name from StageHelper__c where Opportunity__c in:OppList];
 System.debug('Helper' +helperList);
 if(helperList.size()!=0) 
  {
    for(StageHelper__c shl:helperList){
     for(Opportunity oo:OppList) {
   if(!shl.name.equals(Trigger.oldmap.get(oo.id).stagename)){
         SHl.Stage_Change_Date__c=System.Today();
         shl.Age_at_current_stage_days__c=Trigger.oldmap.get(oo.id).Age_at_current_stage_days__c+String.valueof(oo.Age_at_current_stage_days__c);
        update shl;
      } 
  else{
        StageHelper__c SH=New StageHelper__c();
        SH.Name=oo.StageName;
        SH.Stage_Change_Date__c=System.Today();
        SH.Opportunity__c=oo.Id;
        Insert SH;
            }
     }
     } }
}
```

Comment: remove the update sh1 and Insert SH from the for Loop and make a list and add into the list to update in bulk outside the for loop. Can you mention where exactly the issue is in the logic?

Comment: Unable to create records when I change the Stage and if I come to back same stage code is not working...I didn't understand what you meant to say can you modify or share snippet

Comment: I think your If condition is wrong it should be if(!shl.name.equals(oo.stagename) as you need to check the stagehelper with the new stagename.